# Partial derivative of a complex conjugate vector

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, complex-numbers, matrix-calculus

I need to find the partial derivative of $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}$, $f = x^* A^ * y - y^ * A x $ where $x$ and $y$ are complex-valued vectors and * represents the complex conjugate. A is a complex-valued matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$Let $\LR{A^T,A^*,A^H}$ denote the transpose, complex and hermitian conjugates of $A$, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A^* &= \LR{A^T}^H &= \LR{A^H}^T \\
A^T &= \LR{A^H}^* &= \LR{A^*}^H \\
A^H &= \LR{A^*}^T &= \LR{A^T}^* \\
A = \LR{A^*}^* &= \LR{A^H}^H &= \LR{A^T}^T \\
}$$
For typing convenience, define $\,w=\LR{A^Hy}\:$ and Frobenius product $(:)$
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\:norm} \}\\
}$$
Write the function using the above notation and differentiate (in the [Wirtinger](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives) sense)
$$\eqalign{
f &= \LR{w^Hx}^* - \LR{w^Hx} \\
 &= \LR{w:x^*} - \LR{w^*:x} \\
df &= \LR{w:dx^*} - \LR{w^*:dx} \\
}$$
The gradients are therefore
$$\eqalign{
\grad{f}{x^*} &= w = A^Hy,
\qquad\quad 
\grad{f}{x} &= -w^* = -A^Ty^* \\
}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I can say that the first parcel has a partial derivative of zero with respect to x?

Comment: Can I apply this rationale to the function $f = x^* x$  ?

Comment: Yes, in that case $\large{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=x^*}\quad$

Comment: Thank you so much! @greg

Comment: Just to finish my questions.. the derivative with respect to time of $x$ and $x^*$ are transposed conjugates as well, right? This is: $\frac{d x}{dt} = f$ and $\frac{d x^*}{dt} = f^*$